# field injection in mezzanine

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

Following my work with mezzanine, I'm trying to inject a field by:

1>> Adding the EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS in settings.py http://pastebin.com/d5amC7fj and then

2>> Creating the file admin.py http://pastebin.com/zstJNCma under my 'customizations' application.

But when I try the schemamigration, I'm getting an error I can't understand at all //pastebin.com/exLtcQSs.

What am I missing here?

Any and all comments are welcome.

Thanks a lot in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about mezzanine but [looking at the docs](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/model-customization.html#field-injection), it looks like your `EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS` is incorrect:

```
EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS = (
    (   "mezzanine.blog.models.BlogPost.featured_post",
        "BooleanField",
        ("Featured Post",),
        {"blank": False, "null": False, "default": False},
    ),
)
```

notice the brackets around "Featured Post" as this is a tuple of positional args to be passed to the `init()` function.

Comment: Guess you are right ... will check and let you know. Thanks for pointing it put!

Comment: I guess, I'm one step closer ... I  could do the schema migration to the text file, but when I try the migration itself I get error: `ImproperlyConfigured: App with label newsroom is missing a models.py module.' and nowhere in the mezzanine docs does it say I need this file ... and neither do I know what goes in it ... I feel like going into deep water without know how to swim ...